# Visual Studio UML Models for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, uml

I think this should be a simple yes or no answer.

I've added a UML modelling project to an existing standard C++ solution and added to it a reference to the C++ project (VS2015 Enterprise).

I would expect to see my existing C++ classes listed in the UML Model Explorer panel for me to drag onto the diagram, but I don't.

Is this simply because unmanaged C++ is not supported for this tool?

(I know I can right click on the project and do View... Class Diagram, but the diagram produced is not UML and won't even recognize STL containers as associations.)

Comment: Forgive me if it doesn't help as I only vaguely remember talking to someone about the feature last year, but isn't there something like Code Map that will help you see your existing classes and the architechture?

Comment: Having a quick look yielded [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj739835.aspx) sorry if it wasn't much use to you